# How to avoid multiple if/else when filtering resultsets

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a page that has left and right section. right section displays results based on the filters the user chooses on the left. Each time the user chooses the filters on the left and presses a button, I make a query to the server to get the results.

I'm noticing that my if/else clause looks terrible and each time I add a new filter I have to do a lot of work. Is there any way to avoid this?

At the moment I have the following filters: `foo, bar, fromdate, todate, profile`

My if/else looks like this:

```
var query = "?"
if (self.foo === '' && self.bar === '' && self.fromdate === '' && self.todate === '' && self.profile === '')
   query = "";
else if (self.foo.length > 2 && self.bar === '' && self.fromdate === '' && self.todate === '' && self.profile === '')
   query += "foo=" + self.foo;
else if (self.foo.length > 2 && self.bar.length > 2 && self.fromdate === '' && self.todate === '' && self.profile === '')
   query += "foo=" + self.foo + "&bar=" + self.bar;

// ...

xhr.open('GET', apiURL+query)
self.loading = true
xhr.onload = function () {
    self.requests = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText)
    //do stuff
    self.loading = false;
}
```

**Question**
Is there a way to make this if/else easier to understand and manage?

Comment: Using Switch statement (Case) could be easy readable.

Answer (score 2):

What i propose

```
    var queryParams = [
       'foo',
       'bar',
       'profile',
       etc...
    ]
    var query = '';
    queryParams 
       .forEach(key => query = self[key].length > 2 ? 
           query + `&${key}=${self[key]}` : query );
    query = query.length ? '?' + query : query;
```

When you want to add key just update queryParams array no need to touch the logic.

Answer (score 1):

I would do it in a way

```
var query = '?';
query += self.foo.length > 2 ? '&foo=' + self.foo : '';
query += self.bar.length > 2 ? '&bar=' + self.bar : '';
query += self.fromdate ? '&fromdate=' + self.fromdate : '';
query += self.todate ? '&todate=' + self.todate : '';
query += self.profile ? '&profile=' + self.profile : '';
```

And for object

```
var self = {
  foo: "hello",
  bar: "w",
  profile: "me"
}
```

you will get the result `query` as `?&foo=hello&profile=me`. Combination of `?&` in the beginning does not affect the request, so you don't need to remove leading `&`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this example will inspire you. I hope it is simple, declarative and flexible solution - no matter how many inputs you bind to params model in html template, js code stays unchanged.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    params: {}
  },
  computed: {
    query () {
      var query = []
      for (param in this.params)
        if (this.params[param].length > 2)
          query.push(param + '=' + this.params[param])
      query.length
        ? query = '?' + query.toString().replace(/,/g, '&')
        : query = ''
      return query
    }
  },
  methods: {
    submit () {
      console.log('my.url' + this.query)
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <input type="text" v-model="params.foo">
  <input type="text" v-model="params.bar">
  <input type="text" v-model="params.baz">
  <button @click="submit">Submit</button>
</div>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.5.3/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
```